# I have set the headers then also CORS policy error is there(ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, axios

```
axios.get("https://url.example.com/b/478L", {
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    }).then((response) => console.log(response.data))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

My URL is different.

Error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://url.example.com/b/478L' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: What about the back end, You build that?

Comment: No its url of jsonkeeper

Comment: Is there any other solution?

Comment: Look this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe

Comment: Not worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how server is built. But every back-end frameworks have functionality to handle CORS.
For example, in ExpressJS, you can use cors middleware to handle CORS policy.
So try to solve that problem on Server Side.

Comment: Backend is not in my control. Its a url of jsonkeeper

Comment: Is there any other solution?

Comment: @Prem Jogi Please try to set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own back end you can solve this problem.
For an example in Node/Express back end you can use `cors` library [npm link here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Then in your app.js add this line,

```
//IMPORT THE LIBRARY
const cors = require('cors');


//ALLOW REQUEST FROM ANY DOMAIN
app.use(cors());
```

Will fix the error.

If are keep getting this error try different end-point. Or may be you find some thing useful [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)